# Ubuntu 20.04 tries to uninstal nvidia driver everytime i install an program on terminal

Tags: command-line, drivers, nvidia

I'm having this weird problem i didn't have seen anybody getting this issue, i'm very new as linux user and i don't know if this is a simple problem to solve or if i'm just being noob, but everytime i use the apt-get or update on terminal the action is made normally but then after that the terminal shows this [Uninstall Beginning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kPGmy.png)

The nvidia driver isn't in really uninstalled just got a error on final (error 1) and then i'm able to close the terminal, but takes some time until complete this, how can i fix that or prevent this?

EDIT 1:

Here is the entire command line from the terminal, this time i tried to install the smb for sharing files with another computer and again the linux shows a message trying to uninstall my nvidia driver:

```
installArchives() failed: Pr-configurando pacotes ...
Pr-configurando pacotes ...
Selecting previously unselected package python3-dnspython.
(Reading database ... 
(Reading database ... 5%%
(Reading database ... 10%%
(Reading database ... 15%%
(Reading database ... 20%%
(Reading database ... 25%%
(Reading database ... 30%%
(Reading database ... 35%%
(Reading database ... 40%%
(Reading database ... 45%%
(Reading database ... 50%%
(Reading database ... 55%%
(Reading database ... 60%%
(Reading database ... 65%%
(Reading database ... 70%%
(Reading database ... 75%%
(Reading database ... 80%%
(Reading database ... 85%%
(Reading database ... 90%%
(Reading database ... 95%%
(Reading database ... 100%%
(Reading database ... 312573 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../0-python3-dnspython_1.16.0-1build1_all.deb ...
Unpacking python3-dnspython (1.16.0-1build1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package python3-crypto.
Preparing to unpack .../1-python3-crypto_2.6.1-13ubuntu2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking python3-crypto (2.6.1-13ubuntu2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package python3-ldb.
Preparing to unpack .../2-python3-ldb_2%%3a2.0.10-0ubuntu0.20.04.2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking python3-ldb (2:2.0.10-0ubuntu0.20.04.2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package python3-tdb.
Preparing to unpack .../3-python3-tdb_1.4.2-3build1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking python3-tdb (1.4.2-3build1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package python3-samba.
Preparing to unpack .../4-python3-samba_2%%3a4.11.6+dfsg-0ubuntu1.6_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking python3-samba (2:4.11.6+dfsg-0ubuntu1.6) ...
Selecting previously unselected package samba-common.
Preparing to unpack .../5-samba-common_2%%3a4.11.6+dfsg-0ubuntu1.6_all.deb ...
Unpacking samba-common (2:4.11.6+dfsg-0ubuntu1.6) ...
Selecting previously unselected package samba-common-bin.
Preparing to unpack .../6-samba-common-bin_2%%3a4.11.6+dfsg-0ubuntu1.6_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking samba-common-bin (2:4.11.6+dfsg-0ubuntu1.6) ...
Selecting previously unselected package tdb-tools.
Preparing to unpack .../7-tdb-tools_1.4.2-3build1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking tdb-tools (1.4.2-3build1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package samba.
Preparing to unpack .../8-samba_2%%3a4.11.6+dfsg-0ubuntu1.6_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking samba (2:4.11.6+dfsg-0ubuntu1.6) ...
Setting up nvidia-340 (340.108-0ubuntu2) ...
dpkg: error: version '-' has bad syntax: revision number is empty
dpkg: error: version '-' has bad syntax: revision number is empty
dpkg: error: version '-' has bad syntax: revision number is empty
dpkg: error: version '-' has bad syntax: revision number is empty
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
INFO:Enable nvidia-340
DEBUG:Parsing /usr/share/ubuntu-drivers-common/quirks/lenovo_thinkpad
DEBUG:Parsing /usr/share/ubuntu-drivers-common/quirks/put_your_quirks_here
DEBUG:Parsing /usr/share/ubuntu-drivers-common/quirks/dell_latitude
Removing old nvidia-340-340.108 DKMS files...

-------- Uninstall Beginning --------
Module:  nvidia-340
Version: 340.108
Kernel:  5.4.0-050400-generic (x86_64)
-------------------------------------

Status: Before uninstall, this module version was ACTIVE on this kernel.

nvidia.ko:
 - Uninstallation
   - Deleting from: /lib/modules/5.4.0-050400-generic/updates/dkms/
 - Original module
   - No original module was found for this module on this kernel.
   - Use the dkms install command to reinstall any previous module version.


nvidia_uvm.ko:
 - Uninstallation
   - Deleting from: /lib/modules/5.4.0-050400-generic/updates/dkms/
 - Original module
   - No original module was found for this module on this kernel.
   - Use the dkms install command to reinstall any previous module version.

depmod.......

DKMS: uninstall completed.

------------------------------
Deleting module version: 340.108
completely from the DKMS tree.
------------------------------
Done.
Loading new nvidia-340-340.108 DKMS files...
Building for 5.4.0-050400-generic 5.10.9-051009-generic
Building for architecture x86_64
Building initial module for 5.4.0-050400-generic
Done.

nvidia.ko:
Running module version sanity check.
 - Original module
   - No original module exists within this kernel
 - Installation
   - Installing to /lib/modules/5.4.0-050400-generic/updates/dkms/

nvidia_uvm.ko:
Running module version sanity check.
 - Original module
   - No original module exists within this kernel
 - Installation
   - Installing to /lib/modules/5.4.0-050400-generic/updates/dkms/

depmod.......

DKMS: install completed.
Building initial module for 5.10.9-051009-generic
ERROR (dkms apport): kernel package linux-headers-5.10.9-051009-generic is not supported
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 5.10.9-051009-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/nvidia-340/340.108/build/make.log for more information.
dpkg: error processing package nvidia-340 (--configure):
 installed nvidia-340 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 10
Setting up samba-common (2:4.11.6+dfsg-0ubuntu1.6) ...

Creating config file /etc/samba/smb.conf with new version
Setting up python3-tdb (1.4.2-3build1) ...
Setting up tdb-tools (1.4.2-3build1) ...
update-alternatives: using /usr/bin/tdbbackup.tdbtools to provide /usr/bin/tdbbackup (tdbbackup) in auto mode
Setting up python3-ldb (2:2.0.10-0ubuntu0.20.04.2) ...
Setting up python3-dnspython (1.16.0-1build1) ...
Setting up python3-crypto (2.6.1-13ubuntu2) ...
Setting up python3-samba (2:4.11.6+dfsg-0ubuntu1.6) ...
Setting up samba-common-bin (2:4.11.6+dfsg-0ubuntu1.6) ...
Checking smb.conf with testparm
Load smb config files from /etc/samba/smb.conf
Loaded services file OK.
Server role: ROLE_STANDALONE

Done
Setting up samba (2:4.11.6+dfsg-0ubuntu1.6) ...
Samba is not being run as an AD Domain Controller: Masking samba-ad-dc.service
Please ignore the following error about deb-systemd-helper not finding those services.
(samba-ad-dc.service masked)
Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/nmbd.service  /lib/systemd/system/nmbd.service.
Failed to preset unit: Unit file /etc/systemd/system/samba-ad-dc.service is masked.
/usr/bin/deb-systemd-helper: error: systemctl preset failed on samba-ad-dc.service: No such file or directory
Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/smbd.service  /lib/systemd/system/smbd.service.
samba-ad-dc.service is a disabled or a static unit, not starting it.
Processing triggers for ufw (0.36-6) ...
Processing triggers for systemd (245.4-4ubuntu3.4) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.9.1-1) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.31-0ubuntu9.1) ...
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.136ubuntu6.3) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.10.9-051009-generic
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/rtl_nic/rtl8125b-2.fw for module r8169
Errors were encountered while processing:
 nvidia-340
Setting up nvidia-340 (340.108-0ubuntu2) ...
dpkg: error: version '-' has bad syntax: revision number is empty
dpkg: error: version '-' has bad syntax: revision number is empty
dpkg: error: version '-' has bad syntax: revision number is empty
dpkg: error: version '-' has bad syntax: revision number is empty
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
INFO:Enable nvidia-340
DEBUG:Parsing /usr/share/ubuntu-drivers-common/quirks/lenovo_thinkpad
DEBUG:Parsing /usr/share/ubuntu-drivers-common/quirks/put_your_quirks_here
DEBUG:Parsing /usr/share/ubuntu-drivers-common/quirks/dell_latitude
Removing old nvidia-340-340.108 DKMS files...

-------- Uninstall Beginning --------
Module:  nvidia-340
Version: 340.108
Kernel:  5.4.0-050400-generic (x86_64)
-------------------------------------

Status: Before uninstall, this module version was ACTIVE on this kernel.

nvidia.ko:
 - Uninstallation
   - Deleting from: /lib/modules/5.4.0-050400-generic/updates/dkms/
 - Original module
   - No original module was found for this module on this kernel.
   - Use the dkms install command to reinstall any previous module version.


nvidia_uvm.ko:
 - Uninstallation
   - Deleting from: /lib/modules/5.4.0-050400-generic/updates/dkms/
 - Original module
   - No original module was found for this module on this kernel.
   - Use the dkms install command to reinstall any previous module version.

depmod........

DKMS: uninstall completed.

------------------------------
Deleting module version: 340.108
completely from the DKMS tree.
------------------------------
Done.
Loading new nvidia-340-340.108 DKMS files...
Building for 5.4.0-050400-generic 5.10.9-051009-generic
Building for architecture x86_64
Building initial module for 5.4.0-050400-generic
^Cdpkg: error processing package nvidia-340 (--configure):
 installed nvidia-340 package post-installation script subprocess was interrupted
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.31-0ubuntu9.1) ...
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.136ubuntu6.3) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.10.9-051009-generic
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/rtl_nic/rtl8125b-2.fw for module r8169
^Cdpkg: error processing package initramfs-tools (--configure):
 installed initramfs-tools package post-installation script subprocess was interrupted
```

Comment: Can you please repost (add to your question) the error message as text (the entire output of the command)? Pictures of text, especially in this case, don't tell the whole story.

Comment: Please also add the command you are running that gives this output.

Comment: Just edited the post with the entire output, when trying to install the smb support for ubuntu throught the GUI.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question, i figured out how to solve the problem, since i installed the Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS, this system comes with kernel 5.8 which my nvidia driver version isn't supported (nvidia-340) so i had to downgrade to kernel 5.4 to be able to use the proprietary driver instead the nouveau, after this downgrade i started experiencing this problem and this was a conflict having the both kernel in my PC, i don't know why since we can choose which kernel to start up with the system, but i was able to fix by removing the kernel 5.8 and letting only the kernel 5.4 for my nvidia driver.